# How to show status bar notification in unity 3D game in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my game I want to make a mechanism that after using all arrows the player has to wait 30 minutes to play it again. 

So I want that my game will show notifications when the game is ready to play again by showing a notification on status bar of the device even though the player is not in the game. 

I have no idea how to send this notification from my game to the device (Android)status bar. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the status bar for this, it is against the Android design guide. Use notifications and the notification drawer.

See the Android developer docs for more information on notifications: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

See here for a Unity plugin that does all the hard work for you: https://github.com/Agasper/unity-android-notifications